# Parse JSON into C# objects

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am trying to parse a JSON with the following structure in my Unity C# script:

```
{
  "Location1": [
    {
      "text": "Hello!",
      "action": "wave"
    },
    {
      "text": "Welcome!",
    }
  ],
  "Location2": [
    {
      "text": "This will be fun.",
      "action": "talk"
    },
    {
      "text": "Let's go!",
      "action": "happy"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, it is an object of type (I presume) `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>`. Note that `"action"` is **optional**.

I tried implementing classes to interpret the nesting, but no matter what combination or complexity I've gone, I can't seem to get a non-null `dialogue.path`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

[System.Serializable]
public class Event
{
    public string text;
    public string? action;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Dialogue
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<Event>> path;
}

public class Sinterface : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Dialogue dialogue;

    void Start()
    {
        TextAsset json = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("my_dialogue");
        Functions.Log("JSON Loaded: " + json.text); // this works

        dialogue = JsonUtility.FromJson<Dialogue>(json.text);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<Event>> entry in dialogue.path) // NullReferenceException
        {
            Functions.Log("Location: " + entry.Key);
            foreach (Event e in entry.Value)
            {
                Functions.Log("Event Text: " + e.text);
                Functions.Log("Event Action: " + e.action);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I properly "extract" these objects from my JSON into this C# script?

Comment: Deserialize as dictionary without the class. `Dictionary<string, List<Event>> path = JsonUtility.FromJson<Dictionary<string, List<Event>>>(json.text);`

Comment: Thanks @YongShun, I tried that typing in addition to trying with and without `[System.Serializable]` before the `Event` class. `path.Keys.Count` is 0 in both cases.

Comment: `JsonUtility.FromJson()` does not support dictionaries.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/3744182) by Programmer to [Serialize and Deserialize Json and Json Array in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36239705/3744182).  But Unity now has an official port of Json.NET available.  Install `com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json` from the package manager and you should be able to do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Event>>>(json.text)`.

Comment: Huge thanks, @dbc, that worked. I'll update my question/answer with details soon.

Comment: See this question https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/162480/parse-json-in-unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [@dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc) for educating me and advising the usage of **NewtonsoftJSON** (installation instructions [here](https://github.com/applejag/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity/wiki/Install-official-via-UPM#installing-the-package-via-upm-window))

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Sinterface : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private TextAsset jsonFile;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Event
    {
        public string text;
        public string? action;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, List<Event>> dialogue;

    void Start()
    {
        if (jsonFile != null)
        {
            string jsonString = jsonFile.text;
            dialogue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Event>>>(jsonString);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("JSON file is not assigned in Unity Inspector");
        }

        foreach (string locationName in dialogue.Keys)
        {
            Debug.Log(locationName);
        }
    }
}
```